# Token expiration doesn't working - Sanctum, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token, laravel-sanctum

### What I did:

I added token expiration to application that has login system, by changed `null` to `1` minute `expiration` in sanctum.php file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Expiration Minutes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
| considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
| not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.`enter code here`
|
*/

'expiration' => 1,
```

### Problem:

It doesn't work, the app still accept authorized requests all the time. Nothing has changed.

---

**Code**:

- Create token (login):

```
$tokenResult = $user -> createToken('authToken') -> plainTextToken;
return response() -> json([
  'status_code' => 200,
  'access_token' => $tokenResult,
  'token_type' => 'Bearer',
]);
```

- Verify token:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
  
   [Routes]

 });
```

- Delete token (log out):

```
 Auth::user()->tokens()->delete();          
 return response()->json([
     'status_code' => 200,
 ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to clear your config cache. Try to run `php artisan config:clear` in your terminal